# Galleria description over 2 lines

Tags: javascript, galleria

I have just installed the galleria twelve theme and it all works fantastically, except for one thing. We have really long descriptions and ideally need 2 lines for these descriptions (info-text), which I can't seem to get right. Is it something to do with line height?

I have tried following the steps here: http://support.galleria.io/discussions/questions/162-multi-line-toggle-infocaption-in-theme-twelve but I just get a blank description box.

I am very new at this and would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance